# Add multiple plots vertically in the remaining space of page

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, tex

I am knitr-ing this .Rmd, but the result separes subtitle "## PLOTS" away from the three figures i made.

#### first approach

Calculate the reamining space in page and divide it by 3.
out.height='\dimexpr ((\textheight  -3\baselineskip -\parskip -.2em -\abovecaptionskip -\belowcaptionskip)/3)'

#### second approach

Resizing the *out.height* at 25%  reduces and lead space to the subtitle, but nothing happens.

````
---
title: "My report"
output: 
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: pdflatex
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{subfig}
  - \usepackage{calc}
  - \renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.} 
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE)
```

First page. Leaving alone. No figures here

\newpage

## PLOTS

```{r plots, fig.cap = 'My plots', fig.subcap=c('top', 'mid', 'down'), fig.ncol = 1, out.height='\\dimexpr ((\\textheight  -3\\baselineskip -\\parskip -.2em -\\abovecaptionskip -\\belowcaptionskip)/3)', out.extra='keepaspectratio'}
plot(-1:-10)
plot(1:10)
plot(iris$Sepal.Width)
```
````

[image: pdf_result]

Comment: It seems that youare using LaTeX. I usually solve such issues by generating every plot separately, and make their layout with the LaTeX packgage *subfigure*. This also creates figure captions that are consistent with teh document fonts and sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `fig.pos='H'` in the chunk option solves it for me. It requires `- \usepackage{float}` in `header-includes`. [Ref](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Figures)